# Spring Boot Application jar failed to run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, executable-jar

I have a spring boot app and wanted to try to create executable to deploy on the server.
I haven't done this before so I followed instructions and firstly run it through maven - which was running correctly, then I wanted to execute a jar after packaging which resulted in the described error:

```
java -jar target/app.jar


2020-06-26 16:07:18.363  INFO 40372 --- [           main] .l.f.c.FileSynchronizerClientApplication : Starting FileSynchronizerClientApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on DESKTOP-QRMMKEF with PID 40372 (C:\Users\Pawe▒\OneDrive\file-synchronizer-client\target\file-synchronizer-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by Pawel in C:\Users\Pawe▒\OneDrive\file-synchronizer-client)
2020-06-26 16:07:18.367  INFO 40372 --- [           main] .l.f.c.FileSynchronizerClientApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-26 16:07:18.591  WARN 40372 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.FileSynchronizerClientApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/filewatch/FileChangeListener.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2020-06-26 16:07:18.608 ERROR 40372 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.FileSynchronizerClientApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/filewatch/FileChangeListener.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.FileSynchronizerClientApplication.main(FileSynchronizerClientApplication.java:12) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [file-synchronizer-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [file-synchronizer-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [file-synchronizer-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [file-synchronizer-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/filewatch/FileChangeListener.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:56) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:695) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1027) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:385) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:303) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
```

I searched for familiar topics and haven't found the answer, I believe this is something obvious because the app is very simple so as the pom.xml. The class which causes error is not(as it is said in stack trace) in the jar file. Am I something missing which downloads dependencies to jar?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>file-synchronizer-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>file-synchronizer-client</name>
    <description>Simple client-server file synchronizer - client</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <start-class>com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.FileSynchronizerClientApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fracpete</groupId>
            <artifactId>rsync4j-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2-17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.FileSynchronizerClientApplication</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My application.properties file:

```
server.address=127.0.0.1
server.port=8081
client.name = PC1
environment = PROD
logging.level.root = INFO


file.synchronizer.address = http://IP:8888
file.synchronizer.fileList.endpoint=/getFileList
file.synchronizer.setModificationDate.endpoint=/setModificationDate
file.synchronizer.removeFiles.endpoint=/removeFiles
file.synchronizer.logfile.endpoint=/getFileLogList

# rsync configuration
user.local.directory=C:\\clientFiles
rsync.remote.shell=ssh
# ssh configuration
ssh.hostname=server


spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=false
```

My project structure:
[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejkiJ.png)

And my main class:

```
package com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class FileSynchronizerClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FileSynchronizerClientApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, show your `application.properties` file and the project structure

Comment: Hi @EugeneMakarenko, I edited the post as you suggested.

Comment: Add `com.licencjat.filesynchronizer.client.FileSynchronizerClientApplication` too

Comment: Added as you suggested.

Comment: try `spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=true` and check your jar file conatins spring-devtools, I have just build springboot project that contains devtools and I can not see this dependency in my jar file

Comment: I tried and it still doesn't contain devtools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

From [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-devtools)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know they are excluded by default.

Comment: I didn't know this is how it works. I though all my dependencies with runtime scope become part of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you should add this plugins.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </plugin>
```

Can you try

Comment: After I packaged it with mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage the result is the same.

Comment: ı understand sorry ı checked but ı could not found